# Unable to generate ExtentReport for .NetCore App 2.1?

Tags: c#, macos, selenium, .net-core, extentreports

I am working on .NetCore App 2.1 project and I created some selenium scripts in C# for that project with NUnit framework(in MacOS). I am able to execute it successfully. However, I am not able to generate report using Extent Report 3.1.3(Also, Tried 2.41.x), As I am getting warning that It has been restored with .NETFramework 4.6.1, But not with .NetCore app with Project Target framework, while compilinh. When I execute it, It threw me lots of exception. I resolved one by one, by adding Nuget packages. Finally, I am into the following exception, from which I am not able to move further.

```
TearDown failed for test fixture RBAutomationDemo.UnitTest1
TearDown : System.TypeLoadException : Could not load type 'System.Security.Principal.WindowsImpersonationContext' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
--TearDown
 at RazorEngine.Compilation.DirectCompilerServiceBase.CompileType_Windows(TypeContext context)
at RazorEngine.Templating.RazorEngineCore.CreateTemplateType(ITemplateSource 
razorTemplate, Type modelType)
  at RazorEngine.Templating.RazorEngineCore.Compile(ITemplateKey key, Type modelType)
  at RazorEngine.Templating.RazorEngineService.CompileAndCacheInternal(ITemplateKey key, Type modelType)
  at RazorEngine.Templating.RazorEngineService.GetCompiledTemplate(ITemplateKey key, Type modelType, Boolean compileOnCacheMiss)
  at RazorEngine.Templating.RazorEngineService.RunCompile(ITemplateKey key, TextWriter writer, Type modelType, Object model, DynamicViewBag viewBag)
  at RazorEngine.Templating.RazorEngineServiceExtensions.WithWriter(Action`1 withWriter)
  at AventStack.ExtentReports.Reporter.ExtentHtmlReporter.Flush()
  at AventStack.ExtentReports.Model.Report.<>c.<NotifyReporters>b__29_1(IExtentReporter x)
  at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.ForEach(Action`1 action)
  at AventStack.ExtentReports.Model.Report.NotifyReporters()
  at AventStack.ExtentReports.Model.Report.Flush()
  at AventStack.ExtentReports.ExtentReports.Flush()
  at RBAutomationDemo.UnitTest1.OneTimeTearDown()`
```

Please help me on this.

1. Is that possible to use Extent Reports in .NetCore 2.1(in MacOS)? if
   so Please provide me steps to achieve it.
2. If Extent Reports not compatible with .NetCore app 2.1, Please suggest better reporting tool as alternative(pref. open-source)
3. I am going to CI it in VSTS.
   Will reporting be really needed for this scenario separately?

Code I used:

```
using System;
using AventStack.ExtentReports;
using AventStack.ExtentReports.Reporter;
using LocatorsFile;
using NUnit.Framework;
using NUnit.Framework.Interfaces;

namespace RBAutomationDemo
{
    [SetUpFixture]
    public abstract class Base
    {
    protected ExtentReports _extent;
    protected new ExtentTest _test;

    [OneTimeSetUp]
    protected void ReportSetup()
    {
        var dir = TestContext.CurrentContext.TestDirectory + "\\";
        var fileName = this.GetType().ToString() + ".html";
        System.Console.WriteLine(fileName);
        ExtentHtmlReporter htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter(dir + fileName);

        _extent = new ExtentReports();
        _extent.AttachReporter(htmlReporter);
    }

    [OneTimeTearDown]
    protected void ReportTearDown()
    {
        _extent.Flush();
    }



    [SetUp]
    public void BeforeTest()
    {
        _test = _extent.CreateTest(TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Name);
        Initialize();
    }

    [Test]
    public void Testmethod1()
    {
        _test = extent.CreateTest("Checking Total workbooks count");

        try
        {
            _test.Pass("Assertion passed");
            _test.Log(Status.Pass, "Pass");
        }
        catch
        {
            _test.Fail("Assertion failed");
            _test.Log(Status.Fail, "Fail");
            throw;
        }

    }


    [TearDown]
    public void AfterTest()
    {
        var status = TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Outcome.Status;
        var stacktrace = string.IsNullOrEmpty(TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.StackTrace)
                ? ""
                : string.Format("{0}", TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.StackTrace);
        Status logstatus;

        switch (status)
        {
            case TestStatus.Failed:
                logstatus = Status.Fail;
                break;
            case TestStatus.Inconclusive:
                logstatus = Status.Warning;
                break;
            case TestStatus.Skipped:
                logstatus = Status.Skip;
                break;
            default:
                logstatus = Status.Pass;
                break;
        }

        _test.Log(logstatus, "Test ended with " + logstatus + stacktrace);
        _extent.Flush();
        DoTearDown();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Hi Bhuvan, the error message references mscorlib version 4 (i.e. .NET 4.n) and `'System.Security.Principal.WindowsImpersonationContext'` which is very much a windows only class. It looks pretty clear that this code won't run on MacOS. Additionally questions 2 and 3 are really opinion based and not appropriate for Stack Overflow. Better to discuss those within your company.

Comment: Thank you, Richard. But, This means I can not use ExtentReports in MacOS(I dont think so). Or anything else I am missing to make it to work in MacOS. Please guide me on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see below:

1. It is not possible to use ExtentReports with .Net Core/Standard
2. No, it is not compatible and the upcoming version 4 is also not (it is built with .NET Framework 4.5).  If you would like to add support for .NET Core/Standard, I would suggest sending in a pull request (version 4 sources will be available this week).  Note: pull requests will no longer be accepted for version 3 as it is no longer supported
3. This is subjective, it depends upon your team/company setup. There must be other reporting tools that support this need

EDIT:

Version 4 sources are now available, see [here](https://github.com/extent-framework/extentreports-csharp)

As per the project owner (@anshooarora): "I am happy to add support for .NET core but I am still a little skeptical how well supported the required packages are.  I have also been out of touch so I would probably need some help to roll this out."

Answer (score 3):

From the [github site](https://github.com/anshooarora/extentreports-csharp) for ExtentReports: "Current Version: 3.1.0, .NET Framework 4.5+ only."

As .NET 4.5 is windows only, the C# version will only work on Windows. You will need to generate your test reports on windows.

Edit: @foursyth's reply should be considered authoritative, as he works on the Extent Framework.

Comment: Hi @Richard, Thank you for the follow up. Can you please guide me to get other alternatives for reporting in .NetCore application? This will be more helpful for me. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

For those who are looking for a working version of ExtentReports for .NET Core, please take a look on this [fork](https://github.com/simplytest/extentreports-csharp) on top of current version 4.03, which supports not only .NET Core, but even .NET Statndard:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/ExtentReports.Core

Tested only on Windows system, but should also work on Mac OS as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it working, but with a bit of fiddling. The first issue is that dotnetcore is not supported in the default repo of Extent. This is solved by a company called simplytest creating their own currently not accepted PR [here](https://github.com/simplytest/extentreports-csharp).

With this you will still run into an issue however - Extent uses Razor Engine which itself doesn't support non-windows. There is an unmerged fix to this [here](https://github.com/fouadmess/RazorEngine/pull/3/commits).

I have gotten this working within docker (which should be supporting mac also). My instructions from [here](https://github.com/extent-framework/extentreports-csharp/pull/65) will get you to where you need to go.

> The 'COM Interop is not supported on this platform' is an error with the RazorEngine not supporting dotnetcore. This PR contains a potential fix to it #65. I've managed to get Extent working with dotnetcore in a container with your PR's source code and the source code of the RazorEngine PR added to my project as direct project references.
>
> My copy+pasted source code structure is:
>   /src (my stuff)
>
> /Extent/DotnetCoreExtent (your PR)
>
> /Extent/RazorEnginePatch (the PR mentioned)
>
> My project refers to your project, and I've updated your project to reference the RazorEngine patch instead of the nuget reference.

Answer (score 0):

Please update to [ExtentReports.Core 1.0.3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ExtentReports.Core) nuget package which uses the fixed version of RazoreEngine and supports non-windows OS now.

Answer (score 0):

use ExtentReports.Core for .NET core App

also add these nuget packages in any order according to your dotnet core version

- System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager
- MongoDB.Bson
- MongoDB.Driver.Core
- MongoDB.Driver
- Newtonsoft.Json
- RazorEngine.NetCore
  That exception System.TypeLoadException will not occur if you add this nuget package System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.

reference - http://extentreports.com/documentation/